# Retrieve the entirety of imported data using conversational retrieval chain (gpt 3.5)

Tags: openai-api, embedding, information-retrieval, gpt-3, large-language-model

Using the gpt 3.5, I would like to configure the conversational retrieval chain to build a conversation based **on the entirety of the data imported from my CSV file**. Due to the implicit result ranking set up by the conversational model, I only get 4 elements out of 8 (this happens whatever the prompt I use).

Below is an example to explain my case precisely.

*Overview of my data:*

[image]

*This is my python code :*

```
# Import python pacakges
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Import Azure confidentials
load_dotenv()
OPENAI_API_TYPE = os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"]
OPENAI_API_BASE = os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
OPENAI_API_VERSION = os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"]

# Import data
loader = CSVLoader(file_path="data/test_db.csv", encoding="utf-8")
data = loader.load()

# Define embeddings and create vector database
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002", deployment="text- 
embedding-ada-002", chunk_size = 1)
vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(data, embeddings)

# Create conversationnal chain
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0,
                                                             model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo',
                                                             deployment_id="chat",
                                                             request_timeout=10),
                                                  retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever())

# Chat with the data 
chat_history = []
result = chain({"question": "List all transport type do you have", "chat_history": chat_history})
result["answer"]
```

And this is the answer i get :
[image]